# How to idendify the Text in image files and also how to read that text?

Tags: java, algorithm, ocr

In the image format have full of the text. (ie) the scanned document in the format of image file *.tiff. Optical character recognize method only the Normal format of alphabet. In this image format contains the text like running letter. so how to identify and convert the text in to text files?

Comment: open the image file programatically, scan the file, find each character, compare to a rasterized font, store the matching character in an array, and write out the array at the end.

Comment: you need OCR. Just notice that open source OCR usually performs poorly.

Comment: Are you trying to recognize handwritten block letters (each letter written by hand neatly, with space in between), or handwritten cursive words? Handwritten block letter recognition is known as "ICR" (intelligent character recognition). Handwritten cursive word recognition is still at the frontier of research. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_character_recognition

Answer (score 1):

With tesseract-ocr you can train for the characters. If you are sure with running letter font you can use those samples as the training data instead of the default one which ships with it. I haven t done with running letter, but this library is a good place to start with.

http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/

Regards,
Prasanna.

Comment: Tesser-act ocr to perform perfectly convert other type of scanned document. it's very nice job to convert to text file.

Comment: Then my scanned document that in image format. That could not identify the font family and also it written in running letters.